# Minikube not using cache for offline install

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I must install minikube in an airgap environment.
Following the [documentation](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/offline/) I have installed the required specific Kubernetes version on a computer with network access and then copied the files from `.minikube/cache` to the airgap environment.

When creating the minikube cluster on the airgap environment minikube should detect the cached files and use those local images.

> It doesn't...

It always tries to download a specifc image on the internet

```
unable to find image kicbase:0.0.36
```

**It won't be able to download the image but will still carry on and try to find the others images on the internet although they are PRESENT in the cache folder.**

I tried multiple minikube flags but none of them helped minikube find it's local images (image, cache, etc).

Using minikube 1.28
Driver : docker

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.

The minikube's offline install documentation fails to mention the kicbase image. It's not added to the cache folder on the internet PC.

I had to download it manualy on the internet PC :

```
docker pull gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.36
```

Then add it to the offline environment.

On the offline environment I loaded the images (kicbase + the one in the cache folder) to the local docker images.
I don't know if this was really needed for the one presents in the cache folder but anyway I loaded everything and this is how I did it:

- For the ones present in the cache folder (not .tgz but raw docker images)

```
cat <my_image_from_cache_folder> | docker load
```

Yes... You can pipe images to docker...

- For the kicbase image which was .tgz I did:

```
docker load -i kicbase_v0.0.36.tgz
```

Note that a command exists to merge the docker env with the minikube one. I don't think I needed this one as it seems I used it after loading all the image. I'll still provide the command if someone needs it.

```
# Merge docker's env with the minikube's env for the current shell session only
eval $(minikube -p minikube docker-env)
# List images that minikube sees
minikube image ls --format table
```

Finally I started the minikube cluster once again. It found the kicbase image locally and was a happy minikube.
All next images were also taken from the cache (or from the loaded ones from docker ?).
The cluster is now working on the airgap environment !

In the end the real issue was that the documentation does not mention this kicbase image and that when minikube doesn't find it it will then try to download the cached images from the internet. It was like it wasn't detecting the images localy which sends people looking into the wrong direction.